# Where can I find the gas can?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Since first having the gas can, I haven't come across another one. Does anyone know a location or spawn area for it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can buy a "Jerry Can" in ammunation. 
It is to the right of the grenades.

They can also spawn at gas stations (next to the pumps).

Comment: You can also find them at the various petrol stations dotted around.

Answer (score 1):

Simply go to a gas station and look between the pumps.  They simply pop up a short time you pick up the last one. While you wait, find some ballas or vatos to hit with the bat.  Then flip off the cops that show up.